# What does training correlation coefficient means in ANN prediction

Tags: neural-networks

I'm a beginner in statistics with limited knowledge.
I'm reading up on neural networks to predict outputs using inputs.

I understand that a neural network has to be trained to produce the Least mean squared error from the desired output.

What does it mean by training correlation coefficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not very clear to me but if I have understood correctly than this is the answer:

The neural network have to be trained in order to minimize a cost function. 
Usually the cost function is the MSE. In other cases the cost function can be `1 - correlation coefficient`.

Comment: Does it means that, for the cost function (MSE) to be minimum, it will need a suitable correlation coefficient to meet that objective?

Comment: No it means that different cost functions can be used. So you can decide if to minimize the MSE error or the 1-correlation function. There are also other kind of cost functions but these are probably the most common for regression problems